# Characters from a regular expression character set and range

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have some regular expressions that I'm using to create new strings from an input and it's all working fine.
What I'm now trying to do is display the allowed characters from character sets that the regular expressions use.

So for instance I have the regular expression of `[^A-Za-z0-9/_#\-\.]+` that replaces anything outside of that range with nothing (it's for the format of url's that I want).

I have another set which is just `[A-Za-z0-9/_#\-\.]`, which is just the inverse of the above rule. I don't mind that I have the rule twice as they will be made at the same time anyway.

The idea of what I'm wanting is that I can display all the allowed characters in the second expression, so it should read something like: (some remove for brevity)

**A,B,C,D....Z, a,b,c,d....z, 0,1,2,3...9, /, _, #, -, .**

**Is there a way to pull out all of these characters from the regular expression?**

My only idea currently is to parse out the character either size of `-` (where it isn't a space or a comma), and then build up a character set based on the range between the two characters from it's character code.

Has anyone got any slicker ideas? Or something I've missed?
I'll post up my idea once I've done it, unless someone can quickly save me the hassle!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `char` in .NET has only 2<sup>16</sup> possible values, iterating all characters and feeding it to your regex one by one should provide an acceptable solution. If you know that the input is limited to characters from the Latin page, you could limit the brute force check to the initial 256 characters.

```
var rx = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9/_#\\-.]+");
for (char ch = (char)0 ; ch <= (char)255 ; ch++) {
    if (!rx.Match(""+ch).Success) {
        Console.Write(ch);
    }
}
```

This prints `#-./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/QANh43)

Comment: I think that's a perfectly reasonable idea, could 256 regex matches be  pretty brutal though for the simplicity of the output? I could start the char index at 32 though also I think anyway.

Comment: @danrichardson You could collect the output in a string, and then re-order it the way you like. For example, you could write a simple loop that looks for "straight runs", and replace substrings like `0123456789` with a description "any digit" or `0..9` range designator, or something of that nature. I think an exhaustive list of characters is easier to work with than a "black box" regex, though.

Comment: Yes I agree. The regex is always going to be based on an exhaustive list as by the nature of a url, it is anyway. Your solution is definitely worthy of an answer vote anyway as it does do what I asked for. I've modified my code to store the result of the regex, so it only runs once. I'll perhaps run a few tests on it and make my decision on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: efficient and softly sarcastic... +1 :) (`should provide an acceptable solution`?)